# Can't close accordion after update from 2.3.1 to 2.3.5-p1

Tags: javascript, magento2.3.1, magento2.3.5-p1, accordion

**tl;dr** After upgrading from Magento **2.3.1** to Magento **2.3.5-p1** our custom JavaScript, part of our custom theme, stopped working. I'm receiving the following error when trying to close the accordion using the [Magento Accordion](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html) widget like so: `$('#accordion').accordion('deactivate');`

> jquery.js:2 Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on accordion prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'deactivate'

[Full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzVGX.png)

---

I'm using the native [Magento Accordion Widget](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html) in my custom theme. The file contains a single `#accordion`, with a `#readmore` and `#readless` button.
Both are loaded into the DOM, however, the `#readless` button has the default styling: `display: none`

**Block code**

```
<div class="homepage-block">
<div id="accordion" class="fade-active" data-mage-init="{&quot;accordion&quot;:{&quot;openedState&quot;: &quot;active&quot;, &quot;collapsible&quot;: true, &quot;active&quot;: false, &quot;multipleCollapsible&quot;: true}}">
    <div class="row">
            <p>Lorum Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col2-set">
        <div id="readmorecontainer">
            <div id="readmore" data-role="collapsible">Read More...</div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="col-1">
                <p>Lorum Ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <p>Lorum Ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <div id="readlesscontainer" class="col-1">
                <div id="readless">Read Less...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript code**

The JS code has always worked, the functionality is as follows:

- On `#readmore` click

  - Toggle the `#readless` button
  - Toggle `fade-active` class (Pure styling, used as kind of overlay)
- On `#readless` click

  - Toggle `#readmore` button
  - Hide accordion using [Magento's `.accordion('deactivate')`](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html#meth_deact) function.

```
   require([
        'jquery'
        ], function($) {
        'use strict';
    
        $(function() {
    
            // Accordion readmore
            $("#readmore").on("click", function () {
                $('#readmore').hide();
                $('#accordion').toggleClass('fade-active');
            });
    
            // Accordion readless
            $('#readless').on('click', function () {
                $('#readmore').show();
                $('#accordion').accordion('deactivate');
                $('#accordion').toggleClass('fade-active');
            });
        });
    });
```

---

**The issue**

After the update the block, pressing the `#readless` button triggers the error. I guess the `accordion` function changed, or my JavaSript file isn't loaded in the correct order.

Any advice is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying lots of different solutions I've finally managed to fix the problem.

In the JS code I simply had to add 'jquery/ui' to the require.

```
 require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui'
    ], function($) {
    'use strict';
    ...
```

After adding this to the JS and deploying the static content the deactivate method works for the accordion.

I have no idea why this problem only occured after upgrading to Magento 2.3.5-p1.